# Python JSON Iteration into a POST request

Tags: python, json, rest, http-post, httprequest

I have a JSON file that is formatted something like

```
{
   "unknown1": 
   [
        {"text": "random text again",
        "time": "Thu May 15 19:21:59 +0000 2016"}, 
        "text": "akmfkdlm safsa fasffalmfa",
        "time": "Thu May 21 09:53:51 +0000 2016"}
   ]
   "unknown2":
   [ 
        "text": "fsda lmfalmfa",
        "time": "Thu May 21 09:53:51 +0000 2016"},
   ]
}
```

The first item in the JSON is a random (unknown) label and there can be any number of these unknowns. Within these unknowns are always a bunch `text`/`time` pairings.

I am trying to send each `text` into my REST post service which accepts JSON formatted to

```
text: "foo bar bat",
mime_type: "text/html",
extract_type: "HP" # HP, MP
```

So I am getting this error when I try to run my code and I not sure what to do.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests

with open('locations_stripped.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}

for thing in data:
    for text, time in data.iteritems():
        print text
        body = [{ "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}]
        r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
        print (r.content)
```

and here is the error:

```
 $ python filterrest.py
unknown1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filterrest.py", line 30, in <module>
    r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 111, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 298, in prepare
self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 452, in prepare_body
body = self._encode_params(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 89, in _encode_params
for k, vs in to_key_val_list(data):
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

One thing to note is it is printing the wrong text ("unknown1" instead of "random text again") and I am not sure how to get it to only print the text.

Any help on this?

**UPDATE**

Per everyone's answer/comment I changed my code

```
... 
for thing in data:
    for text in data[thing]:
        print text['text']
```

and this prints the text['text'] as I would expect. The issue lies in the way I am doing my request. I changed my code as a test and set the data to something that I know should work (I ran it via [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/%20%22Postman)).

Changed code:

```
r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data='Hello. Where does the brown fox go?', headers=headers)
```

Expected Response:

```
[
  {
    "score": 0.30253747367501777,
    "tag": "HP",
  }
]
```

Instead what gets printed is what looks like an entire HTML page.

Comment: Your Json format is false. Look at here `"text: "akmfkdlm safsa fasffalmfa"`. Your `body` is a `list`. It must be a `dict`

Comment: `for thing in data:
    for text, time in data.iteritems():` is false too ;)

Comment: oops. I was typing up the JSON manually but it is straight from a file so the JSON is definitely valid. Edited the question to be valid though!

Comment: But like i wrote. Int `data=body` `body` must be a `dict`

Comment: Ahhh okay. That seemed to fix the issue but for some reason my request when printed looks like an entire HTML page instead of a response.

Comment: @Joey and what does it look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the part 1 of your question:

```
for thing in data:
    for text, time in data.iteritems():
```

With this loop you won't get the `text`. Your update with:

```
for thing in data:
    for text in data[thing]:
        print text['text']
```

is correct. Your `headers` is right. The next problem is:

```
body = [{ "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}]
r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
```

Now look at the documentation of the module **requests**:

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML
>   form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your
>   dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request
>   is made

> There are many times that you want to send data that is not
>   form-encoded. If you pass in a string instead of a dict, that data
>   will be posted directly.

For keyword parameter `data` you must give either a `dict` or a valid json `str`. Your variable `body` in the question is until a `list` and in your update is a invalid json `str`. There are 2 solutions:

```
body = { "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}
# Dont't forget: dict will be used to send form-encoded data
# It will work. But not a intended solution for json data
r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
```

Or

```
import json
body = { "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}
r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

But the **requests** doc says:

> Instead of encoding the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly
>   using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be
>   encoded automatically

So from the version **2.4.2** it's better to use the keyword parameter `json` instead of `data` to send json data. So it's the best sollution:

```
body = { "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"} 
r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', json=body, headers=headers)
```

**Summarization**

I use this source:

```
{
   "unknown1": 
   [
        {"text": "random text again",
        "time": "Thu May 15 19:21:59 +0000 2016"}, 
        "text": "akmfkdlm safsa fasffalmfa",
        "time": "Thu May 21 09:53:51 +0000 2016"}
   ],
   "unknown2":
   [ 
        "text": "fsda lmfalmfa",
        "time": "Thu May 21 09:53:51 +0000 2016"},
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
import requests

with open('locations_stripped.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}

for list_values in data.values():
    for dict_element in list_values:
        text = dict_element['text']
        print text
        body = { "text": text , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}
        r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', json=body, headers=headers)
        print (r.content)
```

P/S: I don't know your server, so i couldn't test it. I hope, that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid json. You first need to traverse the list corresponding to "unknown" keys, now this list again contains dictionaries
with `text` `time` keys.

```
for unknown_key in data:
    for obj in data[unknown_key]:
         body = { "text": obj['text'] , "mime_type": "text/html", "extract_type": "HP"}
         r = requests.post('localhost:3003/api/extract/run', data=body, headers=headers)
         print (r.content)
```

Comment: I can tell this corrects my issue with inputting the correct `text` as I tried changing my code to yours `for thing in data:
    for text, time in data.iteritems():
        print text` but it appears like my issue lies somewhere else. I have updated my question with the information

Comment: You are sending **text** data in your request while in your headers you have `'Content-Type' : 'application/json'`

Comment: text data? I set the Content-Type to JSON because it expects a JSON.

Comment: 'Hello. Where does the brown fox go?' this is not a json